# YouTube categories in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

I am new to categories in youtube api in Python and I'm encountering issues regarding the language of the videos after I select the region to find videos in.
The problem that I am encountering is that when I enter a region code, it comments on videos that aren't in English even though it's meant to be.
E.G: I enter the region code 'US' and the outcome is what I have attached. It comments on videos that are in a different language.

result [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried to change the region_code="US" in the script but it has problems with 'US' not being defined.
Does anyone know how I can get around this problem or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
API_KEY = "key"

# This function loads the comments in Comments.txt file
def load_comments(file):
    
    comments = []
    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8')
    for comment in f:
        comments.append(comment)
    
    return comments

def search_video(keyword, region_code, comments):
    # Fucntion from Library
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    import datetime
    import time


    def get_category_id(youtube, cat):
        req = youtube.videoCategories().list(part='snippet', regionCode=region_code)
        response = req.execute()
        items_list = response["items"]


        for item in items_list:
            video_category_id = item.get("id")
            if video_category_id is not None: 
                return video_category_id


    def search(youtube, video_category_id=None):
        if video_category_id is None:
            video_category_id = get_category_id(youtube, keyword)
        req = youtube.search().list(videoCategoryId=video_category_id, order='date', maxResults=len(comments),  # q=keyword, 
                                    publishedAfter=(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + 
                                                    datetime.timedelta(minutes = -1)).isoformat('T')+'Z',
                                    part='snippet',type='video')
        return req, video_category_id
    
    api_key = API_KEY
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
    req, video_category_id = search(youtube)
    res = req.execute()
    while len(res['items']) == 0: 
        time.sleep(10) 
        req, _ = search(youtube, video_category_id)  # re-use category id if already found to prevent lag
        res = req.execute()
    videoid = [res['items'][i]['id']['videoId'] for i in range(len(res['items']))]
    
    return videoid
```

(It asks what region to use btw)

Comment: `it has problems with 'US' not being defined` Does it give you an error or warning?

Comment: @RolvApneseth Here is what it says: https://imgur.com/WVvetcW

Comment: On the image your line says `req = youtube.videoCategories().list(part='snippet', regionCode=US)` but shouldn't `US` be a string i.e. `'US'`

Comment: Was that what was causing the problem?